# Reanalyze old data after change analyzer setting in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I re-analyze old documents in an index after I changed analyzer setting of that index. Pls help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have changed your analyzer settings, all you have to do is update your data in place using the [`_update_by_query` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html).

So simply run this and you should be good:

```
POST your-index/_update_by_query
```

Note that if your index is substantially big, the above call will time out before finishing and you'll not really know when it's done. In this case, it's a good idea to add `?wait_for_completion=false` and the update will happen in the background asynchronously. Running the update this way, you'll also get the task ID that you can use to follow the progress using the [Task Management API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tasks.html) with the following command:

```
GET _tasks/<task-id>
```